# cocos2d-x calling ...dispatchCustomEvent(...) many times, is it evil?

Tags: c++, events, listener, cocos2d-x

In my on touch move event listener I call this  `Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->dispatchCustomEvent(_eventname);` .

So it means that, when I move a sprite, it is being called many times. Is it evil? does it badly affects the performance?

Comment: Probably not, but you'd have to measure it to be sure.  Why do you do it this way?

Comment: cocos2d-x has this feature event dispatcher so I tried to use it.. well, it has good performance anyway... one thing i thought about is to use delegation.. i want to expose a virtual method to another class..

Comment: I worked out another way using std::function.. so, I use std::function on my class.. then on the game scene, i used lamba for the definition of the function. .. I think it will result in better performance..